# need to path to parent from child using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, saas

In this  [Family Tree](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree) when we hover on any node all its child nodes will be highlighted. But what I want is when hover or click any node the path to its parent node should highlighted. I have attached sample image of the requirement.[image: pathToParent]. If possible to achieve it, can any one help me in that? It is ok if we can use javascript/jquery also to achieve this.

CSS :

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
    float: left; text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
    display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
    border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

Html :

```
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Parent</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: add some code here

Comment: I don't think it's possible without using javascript, but as Naeem said, add some code.

Comment: I think it's not possible with css. You can't access to parent from child.

Comment: Ivan, It is ok if we can achieve that using javascript.

Comment: CSS is **cascading**, you can't traverse UP the DOM via CSS. It requires scripting.

Comment: is it possible at least to highlight the nodes on the path to parent, instead the line?

Comment: You can't do *anything* "upwards" in CSS. You can only style elements themselves, their children, or their siblings, never parents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/kgd4tsxm/) is how you can highlight the nodes.

**CSS**

```
li.active > a {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
  })
  $('a').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).parents('li').removeClass('active');
  })
})
```

Comment: parent node highlight is excellent. Is it possible to highlight the path also in a similar way?

Comment: Not really sure about it. You might need to change complete structure for it.